# QT json data get error: C2026: string too big, trailing characters truncated

Tags: c++, json, string, qt, std

I meet error about JSON data in QT, [my code on Github](https://github.com/mkzpd/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange) if json data is a bit less, code can be compiled and run, but when json data is a bit bigger, code can't be compiled and run. You can clone my github code to test, I am sure to it can be compiled and run with short json, when you compile done, click `DisplayDirAndFileDifferent` button, you will see below picture:

[image]

When json is short, such as below, code **can** be compiled and run:

```
    const std::string json = R"([
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qmake.stash";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/adxintrin.h.F8695614109264BF.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/algorithm.85F84F593F617683.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/array.4A440D58C35C1B65.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/assert.h.1440D2C4BC469D57.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/atomic.46B98FDAFBC57939.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/bmiintrin.h.575071838DB7E543.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cctype.6CAC01960A46CBE8.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cerrno.D0366719F7F5D6B2.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cfloat.D3E6A7BCFC6D7B8F.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/chrono.0EF46438A07D6958.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/climits.D8FE350A98C8E969.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/clocale.6DAA72D95FD7152A.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""}
])";
```

But Json data is bigger, as like below, code **can't** be compiled and run:

```
    const std::string json = R"([
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qmake.stash";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cmath.892CD3F82046EB21.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/concurrencysal.h.5DA0C09AED7DA192.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/corecrt.h.67FFEE19928F854D.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/corecrt_malloc.h.C0138CCDDEC903D5.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/corecrt_math.h.0390C374A34FAE6B.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/corecrt_memcpy_s.h.57108F1F96D1D502.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/corecrt_memory.h.65CCD44C1265E45E.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/corecrt_search.h.B43E2344530D0FBD.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/corecrt_share.h.DDB39811FDF689B6.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/corecrt_stdio_config.h.58436A96317F9ED9.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cstddef.18387D969F572B40.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cstdint.210D2F1E1255355E.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cstdio.9E31F70803BFA76C.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cstdlib.721BB85373461AF5.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cstring.8985911536AFC237.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/ctime.1EFA885321907197.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/ctype.h.BC399C448EA6DADA.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cwchar.1B862937C4978721.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/eh.h.F7CF178131C9CC77.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/emmintrin.h.6E9074898208EE3A.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/errno.h.FE9F83F635964CFD.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/exception.68221D83EEE0C979.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/filesystem.EEB58F510895B243.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/float.h.007015653F756B29.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/float.h.D55989CBB4E7EEA3.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/functional.F7983FBAA4462BCB.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/fxsrintrin.h.C52DDDDFB7A8B9DB.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/ia32intrin.h.3E30D2C597639933.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/immintrin.h.33FF6DAB2F686F5A.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/initializer_list.EE3DCE14C35AE786.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},





...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...




{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/intrin.h.411A625DDB615A10.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/intrin0.h.19F5FEEAE1E7457C.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/intrin0.inl.h.5D396B7ADE2D7A7B.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/iomanip.1D639BBCDBA1F3D0.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/ios.6E488EB20885070C.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/iosfwd.AE9C5D6643157A02.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/isa_availability.h.8CE89F7382834217.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/qimage.h.67597433C49CD802.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/qinputmethod.h.77B22054D6EE2814.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""}
])";
```

Here is [My test data](https://pastebin.com/L7qL037M), I think the data is not very big, because it just a section test data of [I write application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76750667/how-to-display-tree-folder-to-qt-treeview).

I Google search, but no find a approach to solve it. I need to compare modify date of directory and files to find what directory and files changed, directory and files is not fixed because user may be want to check some directory's file changed. See [What do for I write application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76750667/how-to-display-tree-folder-to-qt-treeview).

I read @BoP provided link [Compiler Error C2026](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2026?view=msvc-170). See below picture:

[image]

#### I think my problem not only about string, but also about `JSON` format. What format should I write directory path to file and how I use it in json format.

How could I solve this problem? Thank you. **JSON format can be very flexible, as long as the code works correctly.**.

### First Update

When I use @drescherjm provided link [code](https://ideone.com/X7redR), I get error see below picture(But I think the error is every line without end with comma, `but except for the last line`, see Four Update that can work json format):

[image]

### Second Update

When I use @Jarod42 answer, I get error see below picture:

[image]

### Third Update

I [provided link](https://pastebin.com/L7qL037M) every line end with comma, `but except for the last line`, see below picture:

[image]

### Four Update

When json data is short, progrma can be compiled and run. The json is:

```
    const std::string json = R"([
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qmake.stash";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/adxintrin.h.F8695614109264BF.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/algorithm.85F84F593F617683.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/array.4A440D58C35C1B65.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/assert.h.1440D2C4BC469D57.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/atomic.46B98FDAFBC57939.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/bmiintrin.h.575071838DB7E543.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""}
])";
```

See below picture:

[image]

Comment: The MS help page for [Compiler Error C2026](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2026?view=msvc-170) says that there is a limit of 16380 chars. And that the solution is to split it up in several smaller strings, that can then be concatenated.

Comment: @BoP Because I need to write directory path to file, then I need to read file by json format, Can you say more details? It seems that my approach is similar to approach in your provided link.

Comment: What the MS help *tries* to say is that each string has a size limit, but you can use several smaller strings instead. If you have two small strings `"Hello" "World"` close to each other in the source, they will be combined into one larger string.

Comment: Adjacent string literals will be concatenated automatically, it's a little known feature of C++.

Comment: @BoP But my problem  not only about string, but also about JSON format.

Comment: @john But my problem not only about string, but also about JSON format.

Comment: This could help: [https://ideone.com/X7redR](https://ideone.com/X7redR) look at lines 14 and 15

Comment: Have you read the link? either store data in a resource file, or split the string in smaller parts.

Comment: That is a good point a Qt resource file would work great for this.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I read the link, I need to write directory path to file, then I need to read file by json format.

Comment: The question is why can't you do what the link told you to do? What is stopping you from breaking the string up in multiple parts? I showed you an example @ ideone. If that is too painful, the Qt resource file example is probably your best bet. And that would not require the string to be broken up.

Comment: Error is because of limitation of msvc compiler about literal C-string. They propose one alternative solution (resource file (which is easy with Qt)) and a work-around (concatenate adjacent split strings).

Comment: @drescherjm Every line without comma seem to can't work in my github code, it get json format error.

Comment: *"I think my problem not only about string, but also about JSON format."* Have you tried proposed solutions about strings, and why do you think it is about json format?

Comment: @Jarod42 Before I get error when every line without comma, I try to use again your code.

Comment: @Jarod42 I try to use you provided link, but I get error, please see my updated question.

Comment: Not my link. And we don't know how you split your string, you might have typo (as missing comma...

Comment: @Jarod42 sorry, I see error. I changed my answer.

Comment: If the json data requires a `,` on every line even the one before `]` you should add one to @Jarod42's answer. I use xml in Qt so far and not so much with json.

Comment: @drescherjm requires a comma , is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021468/make-tree-folder-from-qtreeview-or-qtreewidget answer's code. But if without comma can solve problem is also good.

Comment: [OT]: temporary objects should not be versioned.

Comment: @Jarod42 "temporary objects should not be versioned" about this, I don't understand well, what this mean? I now test json data, do you have a better approach/method?

Comment: I go in you github repo, and whole directory `build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug` should not be versioned (that directory might be in [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: @Jarod42 I understand what you mean. Put the files that don't need to be tracked for changes in the gitignore. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is because of limitation of msvc compiler about literal C-string. They propose one alternative solution (resource file (which is easy with Qt)) and a work-around (concatenate adjacent split strings).

For the workaround, it would be something like:

```
    const std::string json = R"([
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qmake.stash";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/adxintrin.h.F8695614109264BF.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/algorithm.85F84F593F617683.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/array.4A440D58C35C1B65.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
)" // First part
R"(
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/assert.h.1440D2C4BC469D57.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/atomic.46B98FDAFBC57939.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/bmiintrin.h.575071838DB7E543.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cctype.6CAC01960A46CBE8.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cerrno.D0366719F7F5D6B2.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/cfloat.D3E6A7BCFC6D7B8F.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/chrono.0EF46438A07D6958.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
...
...
...
)" // other parts

R"({"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/QHBoxLayout.B54878B25703D6EF.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/QHeaderView.5F173F2D6020F3BC.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/qheaderview.h.9D687AEA36A2B403.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/qicon.h.8DA53B9D01FED295.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/qimage.h.67597433C49CD802.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""},
{"name": "C:/my-win10-document/code/CheckDirectoryAndFileChange/build-CheckDirectoryAndFileChange-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc_clangd/.cache/clangd/index/qinputmethod.h.77B22054D6EE2814.idx";"LastModifiedTime": ""}
]
)"; // Last part
```

As you use Qt, I really suggest to use resource file (.qrc) instead.

See their [help page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

Comment: I use your code get error, please see my updated problem.

Comment: @Tom: Assuming original string was correct, you might have introduced "typo" during the split.

Comment: As debugging purpose, write the string into a file, and validate the file content with any json validator.

Comment: Please see my  second third and third update  about every line end with comma.

Comment: You use `;` instead of `,` to separate field (Error: Parse error on line 2: 
...-Debug/.qmake.stash"  **ERROR>;<ERROR** "LastModifiedTime). Got it by copy pasting your json in first json validator link...

Comment: You have same issue with your short json...

Comment: "You have same issue with your short json", you are wrong, about this please see my four updated problem.  About "You use ; instead of , to separate field (Error: Parse error on line 2: ...-Debug/.qmake.stash" ERROR>;<ERROR "LastModifiedTime). Got it by copy pasting your json in first json validator link" I say that JSON format can be very flexible, as long as the code works correctly.. And if possible,  Please take another look at the beginning of my question,  thank you.

Comment: Now that your too long string is fixed, open a new question about json issue (and there, you have to show how you read your ("invalid") json).

Comment: This question I brought has the JSON tag. At the begin, I say short json can work, but long json can't work.

Comment: I tried your git repo, and the split way works, once placeholder `...` removed, and typo (missing `]`) fixed, It even works with the big string, split by `)" R"(` in the lines spot by compiler.

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/TxqJGV9C

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TxqJGV9C, code in this link can be compiled and run, that is very good. Can you explain more details in your answer? How can I use it better?

Comment: The difference between pastebin and my answer is just the source json which is different. The one in question has `...` and possibly typo to close the array.

Comment: I found. About `The one in question has ... `, can you make the ... more prominent? Or add a comment after ..., indicating that changes need to be made here.

Comment: It was from **your** data...

Comment: I mean about `The one in question has ...` , can you make the ... more prominent `in your answer`? Or add a comment after ..., indicating that changes need to be made here(`in your answer`). If anyone encounters a similar problem in the future, they will be able to understand your solution more quickly.